# Windows 7 lowers applications' volume automatically

Tags: windows-7, audio

Every time I run some of my games, if the media player is open and playing, Windows 7 lowers the volume of both applications (the game and the player). All other applications are not affected. I tried foobar and Winamp, combined with several games, and it happened every time, which makes me think it’s a Windows 7 thing.

The volume goes down to inaudible levels (usually 3 or 4), and I’m forced to alt+tab, open the volume mixer, and increase both volumes manually every time.

This also doesn’t look like a bug, but some kind of feature. When it happens, the little bar in the volume mixer that shows each application’s volume level gets a little transparent (but stays in it’s regular position), while a new one appears and tells the new volume.

Anyone know what’s causing this?

(The games ran from steam, in case it matters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8 turns program sound volume down randomly](https://superuser.com/questions/504004/windows-8-turns-program-sound-volume-down-randomly)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Windows 7 automatically lowers speaker volume when it detects communication activity (A microphone-enabled game for example). You can turn this off though.

- Navigate to:

**Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Sound -> Audio properties -> Communications tab**

- Select **Do Nothing** from the dropdown box. Apply & OK.

[image: Communications tab of Sound dialog in Windows 7]

Comment: Damn, I was uploading to TinyPic when I saw you answered. Always beating me to the punch. lol

Comment: Thanks, that's been driving me nuts. This stupid microphone doesn't even work right and it's still giving me headaches.

Comment: http://i47.tinypic.com/erleyq.jpg ;)

Comment: LOL... nice "bug".

Comment: That dialog is composed of radio buttons instead of a dropdown in my Windows 7 SP1. Is it just me or everyone has it as radiobuttons now?

Comment: It's not a "feature" if people think it's a bug.

Comment: @Win7ftw Its a bug until people realize its a feature.

Comment: It actually does this _when I play a midi in Winamp_.  Tell me that's "communications activity"

Comment: Thanks, that was driving me nuts! And for me it didn't even seem to be connected to communications or mic use, it was just happening spontaneously. And it only seemed to affect Google Chrome. Weird.

Comment: There **does** seem to be a related, actual bug causing it to happen randomly; or at least an errant third-party application triggering it. It has happened to me watching Flash videos in Firefox, listening to music in foobar2000, or watching a video in VLC. In all cases, it happened after several minutes of me not touching the computer at all. I don't even have a microphone connected to this PC. I would also add that while volume reduction is active, the Volume Mixer application is slow to the point of being almost unresponsive. Definitely smells "buggy" to me.

Comment: Yeah, the bug is that it detects completely random things (the lid opening, for example, or a Secret Project video in SMAC) as "communication activity".

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to you in Winamp when you play a MIDI back, you need to [change the midi output device to DirectMusic](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?s=&threadid=166526)