# Volume key occassionally changes relative volume in mixer

Tags: windows-7, audio

I find this a bit of a nuisance but I usually use the "volume up/down" key on my Microsoft ergo 4000 to change the volume of my system.

The problem I'm experiencing is *every so often*, the volume of Winamp goes way down relative to the other apps in the mixer:

[image: winamp drops]

So I don't always notice this right away, suddenly I can't hear Brandy warbling.  And that makes me sad.  Or mad.  Or both.  But it's a nuisance - is there a special key combination I need to *avoid* pressing to stop the mixer from imbalancing?  Is there a way to disable this "app specific" mixer, because it is completely useless to me.

Comment: (Turns out) related: http://superuser.com/questions/74116/windows-7-lowers-applications-volume-automatically/74117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a similar problem with different programs. The solution for me was to change the behavior of Windows when it detects communications. Right-click on the windows volume icon, open "Sounds" from the context menu, then go to the "Communications" tab and select the "Do nothing" option.

Comment: This is actually the right answer. [See here](http://superuser.com/a/74117/2032)

Answer (score 5):

The app-specific volume set in that panel should be equal to the volume set in Winamp itself.

Just set Winamp to maximum volume and control the main volume from then on. You might find it helpful to completely disable Winamps own volume adjustment.

1. Open the **Winamp Preferences**, go to **Plugins** and select the **Output** category.
2. Select the **Nullsoft DirectSound Output** plugin and click **Configure**.

   [image]
3. On the **Other** tab, uncheck **Enable volume control** and click **OK**.

   [image]