# Why do my Stereo Mix levels keep reverting to 50%?

Tags: windows-8, audio, visualization

I'm kind of obsessed with music visualization.  On my new Windows 8 laptop I have it all set up to use Stereo Mix, but every once in a while my vis doesn't seem to be reacting well.  Whenever I notice this, I go check and sure enough...

[image]

**I want it to stay at 100%.**

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: 100%?  I've changed it a dozen times today alone.

Comment: I thought it would be easy to infer that from the title of the question, but I guess I'll update for clarification...

Comment: Haha, sorry, I was staring at the picture and completely forgot the title. May not be related, but I was having a problem with output dropping and [this answer helped me](http://superuser.com/questions/504004/windows-8-turns-program-sound-volume-down-randomly).

Comment: Yeah, I set that to "Do Nothing" a while back.  Didn't help this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled audio enhancements and it worked here.

[image]

(I realize this is a 10 y/o question, but was still my first search result)

Comment: This of course is no longer an issue for me personally but I'll accept this answer as it seems plausible and there are no others. Welcome to SU!