# Bizarre volume dropping issue

Tags: windows, audio

I'm having a bizarre issue with my volume. If I'm watching something with MPC (Media Player Classic) and my room mate turns his laptop on or off, the windows volume for MPC will drop to 0.

It happens every time without fail. I ran wireshark and looked at incoming traffic but nothing readable stood out. There was plenty of TCP traffic though.

Both machines are windows 8.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Switch off WiFi and LAN. Try again to see if the issue is occuring again.

Comment: Tried. It only happens when his laptop is connected to the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sound card setting in Communications tab, try changing "When Windows detects communications activity" to Do nothing.

Find detail steps in the accepted answer to this question.

[Windows 8 turns program sound volume down randomly](https://superuser.com/q/504004/143512)

Comment: That setting solved it but I'd like to know what caused it. Why would Windows 8.1 think there was some communications activity when my room mate turned on/off his laptop?

Comment: I think it is bug in windows or may be a bug in any third party drivers. Many people have reported similar issues.....