# Chrome suddenly lowers sound volume

Tags: windows, google-chrome, audio, windows-8.1

When I use Chrome to listen to music, sometimes the volume suddenly goes down. Other sounds are just normal. This is the Windows Sound mixer shows:

[image]

The volume meter on Chrome has 2 indicators. I have no Skype or any communication application on at that time.

My Chrome version is "Version 36.0.1985.125 m" (newest up to now). Here is the extensions list:

[image]

What is the problem with Chrome? How can I fix it? It is quite annoying that I have to move the volume up everytime this happens.

Comment: Which Chrome version are you currently using? Can you reproduce the issue when logging in with a different account?

Comment: My Chrome version is the newest (Version 36.0.1985.125 m). The problem occurs very randomly, and I cannot reproduce the problem on my own, but it did happen many times.

Comment: Also, which extensions have you installed?

Comment: I added the picture including all the extensions of my browser. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Although you said the problem is rare, do you remember if Chrome was the only affected program all the time? This question might be of interest: [Windows 8 turns program sound volume down randomly](http://superuser.com/questions/504004/)

Comment: It may be that problem. I disabled it. Although I do know about this problem, and at that time, Skype is not opened. I will wait for some time to see if this will happen agian.