# Audio from VLC will get quiet when focusing other applications

Tags: google-chrome, audio, windows-8.1, vlc-media-player

OS: Windows 8.1

I'm noticing that when playing something from VLC (though it happens when playing audio from Chrome) that my sound will pseudo-randomly become quiet.

Chiefly it happens on the 'new tab' screen of google chrome, as well as google searches through windows chrome. It will occasionally happen when I open other applications - though I've not yet found any rhyme or reason to it.

Device is the built-in realtek device through my headphone jack, driver is most current according to their website.

Not really sure how to diagnose or fix this. Help appreciated.

EDIT: Logging in as a different user fixes the issue. Disabling all extra chrome extensions does not. Still looking for a solution for my regular user account.

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/760413/win8-volume-keeps-changing-when-switching-programs-or-switching-to-new-tab-in-c

List of things causing the issue:

- Chrome
- Launching a windows 7 virtualbox VM (not VBox manager though)
- Mumble
- Will update with more as found
- NOT Foobar2000 (I had suspected the issue may be coming from applications that play sound?)
- Installed Skype to test, during the initial 'setup' of my account (for sound/mic/video) my audio was hushed, despite that I have the 'communications activity' set to 'do nothing'.

Comment: Try while logged in as a different user. Make any difference?  When the volume changes, is the change reflected in the audio mixer?

Comment: It works properly as a different user. So I guess it's a user setting or a chrome setting? Change isn't reflected in the mixer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 lowers applications' volume automatically](http://superuser.com/questions/74116/windows-7-lowers-applications-volume-automatically), [Windows 8 turns program sound volume down randomly](http://superuser.com/questions/504004/windows-8-turns-program-sound-volume-down-randomly)

Comment: Nope - I tried both of those before posting the question.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 if you're curious, I've found the solution and posted it as an answer

Comment: Nice, glad to hear you figured it out. So in the end, it's a duplicate of [Windows 8 Communication Sound Setting not working](http://superuser.com/questions/538723/windows-8-communication-sound-setting-not-working/662466#662466). But this one is better IMO anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/662466/329403)

I unchecked "Allow application to take exclusive control of this device". Not the best way to go about it, but it works and since I rarely use the built-in mic I doubt I'll have an issue.

[image]