# Limited volume when using Bluetooth headset with computer

Tags: audio, drivers, bluetooth

So I've got this pretty cool Bluetooth headset that sounds amazing on both my Phone and Computer.

I'm using the Broadcom Driver to allow me to stream the audio in high quality (not in standard phone quality).

Now the problem is, some times, and only some times, when I link the bluetooth headset to my computer, the volume is limited. I cannot, in any way, adjust the volume from my computer. I can do it with the volume slider on my headset, but that (obviously) doesn't have any affect on my computer volume. The only way I can get around this is to restart my computer every time it happens.

The little volume icon in my task bar stays fixed (to whatever volume it was set to, when connecting the device). When I click the icon to bring up the volume control, and change it, nothing happens. The slider goes to the desired position, and it even makes that little noise, but nothing actually happens to the volume (or to the little icon in the task bar).

This usually happens when I'm playing music and connect my headset to the computer, without stopping the music, first. However, there has been many other times when it's happened without playing any music at all.

Any ideas?

This also never happens on my Phone.

Comment: Try [this](http://superuser.com/a/74117/138343) and let us know if it helped.

Comment: @Karan Just tried it. The issue still remains :(

Comment: Which OS you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth connection failed to set up your audio profile and instead of failing it tried to handle it gracefully by falling back on one of the older basic audio profiles, indicated by the fact that absolute volume is not supported when this happens.

It should be solved by dropping the bluetooth connection and re-connect.

I would be surprised if there is a permanent fix that solves this, you will probably have to re-connect each time this happens.