# Windows is Auto Adjusting Volume of Applications

Tags: audio, windows-8.1

Windows keeps auto adjusting my sound, especially when using applications such as skype.  I want to disable this.  I have already changed the settings to tell windows "to do nothing" in the communication tab, but it still reduces the volume (although it doesn't move the tab in the mixer thing).  How can I make the volume not be auto adjusted?

This most often occurs when I am watching youtube and start a call on skype.  It then reduces the sound of youtube for the duration of the call.  This is not just skype, it does similar things on chatroulette and other things of that sort.

I have windows 8.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 lowers applications' volume automatically](http://superuser.com/questions/74116/windows-7-lowers-applications-volume-automatically)

Comment: That link just offers the solution I mentioned already trying. (I didn't have a high enough score to comment on that page)

Comment: What sound drivers do you show in device manager? Maybe you have non-standard software doing this.